# What does Linux' chown '-R' parameter mean?

Tags: linux, chown

The explanation is:

> "-R, --recursive
>
> operate on files and directories recursively"

What does "recursive" mean here?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

"Recursive" implies that the operation will be performed for all files and directories (and all files and directories within any directory).  So

```
chown -R foo /some/path
```

would change file owner to `foo` for all files and directories in `/some/path`

p.s.  You might have even seen the dictionary entry for `recursive`:

> recursive, *n*: See *recursive*

Comment: Search `recursion` in Google, and it says: `Did you mean: recursion`

Comment: See, I already told you!

Comment: @Random Google... genious

Comment: don't forget about user groups `chown -R user:group /some/path`

Answer (score 3):

In some Linux commands, if you run the command on a **folder** with `-R`, the command will operate on all files and folders in that folder's tree. If you run the command on a **file**, `-R` has no effect.

The command will operate on given folder, and *recursively* operates on files and folders within it. It is based on [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29).

For example, you can remove a folder and its contents with

```
rm -R folder-name
```

Or you can find all occurrences of a specific string in all files within current folder tree with

```
grep -R -n the-string .
```

In this example `-n` is for displaying line numbers.

Answer (score 2):

It means apply it to sub-directories and their contents, that is, *recurse* `chown()` when a directory is encountered.